# Mysql Error for using Delimiters in triggers

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, delimiter

This is my mysql trigger statement

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER kk AFTER UPDATE
    ON location FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
        IF NEW.name not in(SELECT A.name FROM filter A  WHERE (NEW.name = A.name))THEN  

        IF NEW.location_name != OLD.location_name THEN
            INSERT INTO filter(old_location_name,new_location_name) 
            VALUES (OLD.location_name, NEW.location_name);

        ELSE
            
                UPDATE filter SET old_location_name = OLD.location_name , new_location_name = NEW.location_name WHERE name = OLD.name;  

        END IF; 

        ELSE

            UPDATE filter SET old_location_name = OLD.location_name , new_location_name = NEW.location_name WHERE name = OLD.name;

  
        END IF; 
              
  END;|
DELIMITER ;
```

This works fine, when i paste this code in phpMyadmin.

And in my project

```
$sqlDrop = "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `kk`";       
$resDrop = parent::_executeQuery($sqlDrop); 

echo $sql = "same above delimiter trigger query";
$rs = parent::_executeQuery($sql );
```

Now the `$sql` statement echos in a single line

```
 DELIMITER | CREATE TRIGGER kk AFTER UPDATE ON location FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.name not in(SELECT A.name FROM filter A  WHERE (NEW.name = A.name))THEN IF NEW.location_name != OLD.location_name THEN INSERT INTO filter(old_location_name,new_location_name,name) VALUES (OLD.location_name, NEW.location_name);    ELSE UPDATE filter SET old_location_name = OLD.location_name , new_location_name = NEW.location_name WHERE name = OLD.name; END IF; ELSE UPDATE filter SET old_location_name = OLD.location_name , new_location_name = NEW.location_name WHERE name = OLD.name; END IF; END;| DELIMITER ;
```

And the query is not executed. And when i paste the echoed statement in my phpMyadmin, its showing me an error

[image]

So what could be the problem. Is it the right way of executing trigger queries?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about any PHP related issue but try modifying your trigger code like below

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER kk AFTER UPDATE
    ON location FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
        IF NEW.name not in(SELECT A.name FROM filter A  WHERE NEW.name = 
A.name) AND NEW.location_name != OLD.location_name THEN      
            INSERT INTO filter(old_location_name,new_location_name) 
            VALUES (OLD.location_name, NEW.location_name);    
        ELSE    
                UPDATE filter SET old_location_name = OLD.location_name ,
 new_location_name = NEW.location_name WHERE name = OLD.name;      
        END IF;     
END;|
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this really helps you. How about Executing each queries seperately?

```
$startDelimit = 'DELIMITER |';
$resStart = parent::_executeQuery($startDelimit);
```

Then your create trigger statement

```
$sql = "CREATE TRIGGER kk AFTER UPDATE ...... END IF; END;";
$rs = parent::_executeQuery($sql );
```

And then last statement

```
$endDelimit = '| DELIMITER ;';
$resEnd = parent::_executeQuery($endDelimit );
```